# Cluster labels are not visible - ArcGIS javascript API 4.19

Tags: angular, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api, esri-maps

When we remove any layer from the group layer after that label are not visible for all layers.

We tried to 'loadAll' method group layers still issue is there. I tried with ArcGIS API 4.22 also.

We created one POC on the same issue:
Steps

1. From Expand Legend (left side) click  Group 1 and then click Group 2 once.
2. Now expand TOC (right side) and  expand predefined group layer  and click on del button (red background) for layer 'Accidental Deaths'.
3. Now re-open TOC and click on the cluster button for all layers.

You will observe labels are not visible on cluster points.
Below issue screenshot
[image]

**Sample Code to reproduce the issue**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cli-esri-map3-p7bpym?file=src%2Fapp%2Fesri-map%2Fesri-map.component.ts

**Question**- why labels are not visible when we remove one layer from the group layer.

Comment: I am also facing similar issue while using esri cluster with esri group layer................ ,

Comment: As I can see in screenshot,  i am also able to add clusters even only cluster count is not showing , All the requested cluster params I ahve already verified plus I can see cluster count properly without removing a sub layer from the group.. Same i can see in sample code attached to the question..

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, and it's resolved on ArcGIS version 4.23.